# Get one linked server property

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I use SQL Server 2014, I also have a linked SQL Server configured on it, and I need to get a particular linked server property via TSQL. The property is 'remote proc transaction promotion'. I set this option through the next code

```
EXEC sp_serveroption 'LinkedServer', 'remote proc transaction promotion', 'FALSE'
```

but I do not know how I can read the value of this option via T-SQL. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sys.servers` system catalog view has a record for each registered linked or remote (for backward compatibility) server.  The `is_remote_proc_transaction_promotion_enabled` column corresponds to the `remote proc transaction promotion` option of the `sp_serveroption` stored procedure.  This column is of the bit data type, with true represented by `1` and false by `0`.

```
select is_remote_proc_transaction_promotion_enabled from sys.servers where name = 'LinkedServer'
```